# Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1 on updating of an entity via hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, stalestateexception

When trying to update an entity from the controller, I keep getting this exception. Rest assured, thorough research regarding this exception has been made, but none of the suggestions have worked in my case.

I am trying to update the doctor entity by calling hibernate `session.update(entity)`;

```
Doctor model:
    @Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_doctor")
public class Doctor {

private Long id;
private PersonInfo personInfo;
private String licenseNumber;
private User user;
private String specialization;
private String employmentStatus;
private String suffix;
private List<Patient> patients;


//
// @OneToMany
// @JoinTable(name = "Doctor_Appointment", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name
// = "doctor_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = //
// "appointment_id") })
// private List<Appointment> appointments;

public Doctor() {
    super();
    user = new User();
    personInfo = new PersonInfo();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String patients= "";
    for(Patient p: this.patients) {
        patients += p.toString();
    }

    return "Doctor [id=" + id + ", personInfo=" + personInfo
            + ", licenseNumber=" + licenseNumber + ", user=" + user
            + ", specialization=" + specialization + ", employmentStatus="
            + employmentStatus + ", suffix=" + suffix + ", patients="
            + patients + "]";
}

@Column(name = "fld_license_number")
public String getLicenseNumber() {
    return licenseNumber;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "key_user")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

@Column(name = "fld_specialization")
public String getSpecialization() {
    return specialization;
}

@Column(name = "fld_employment_status")
public String getEmploymentStatus() {
    return employmentStatus;
}

@Column(name = "fld_suffix")
public String getSuffix() {
    return suffix;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "key_patient")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
public List<Patient> getPatients() {
    return patients;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "key_doctor")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "key_person_info")
public PersonInfo getPersonInfo() {
    return personInfo;
}
//setters
```

}

Person info just includes the biodata like first name, last name, sex, birthday etc.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update_doctor.it", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateDoctor(HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("doctor") Doctor     doctor, Model model, @RequestParam("id") long adminId) {
        System.err.println("update doctor controller");
        String username = session.getAttribute("user").toString();
        session.setAttribute("user", username);

        doctor.getUser().setEnabled(true);
        doctor.getPersonInfo().setDateModified(LocalDate.now());
        doctorDao.updateDoctor(doctor);
        return "redirect:/view_doctor_profile.it?id=" + doctor.getId();
    }
```

DaoImpl

```
@Override
public void updateDoctor(Doctor doctor) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(doctor);
}
```

JSP

```
form:form class="docForm" method="post" commandName="doctor" action="update_doctor.it?id=${adminUser.getId() }" >
    <section>
        <header>

            <h3>Doctor Information</h3>
        </header>
    <form:hidden path="id" value="${doctor.id}" />

    <ul class="fields">
        <li><label>First Name</label>:<form:input value="${doctor.getPersonInfo().getFirstName()}" path="personInfo.firstName" type="text" required="true" /></li>
        <li><label>Last Name</label>:<form:input value="${doctor.getPersonInfo().getLastName()}" path="personInfo.lastName" type="text" required="true" /></li>
        <li><label>Suffix</label>:<form:input value="${doctor.getSuffix() }" path="suffix" /></li>
        <li><label>License Number</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getLicenseNumber() }" path="licenseNumber" /></li>
        <li><label>Occupation</label>:<form:input value="${doctor.getPersonInfo().getOccupation() }" path="personInfo.occupation"  /></li>
        <li><label>Specialization</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getSpecialization() }" path="specialization" required="true"/></li>
        <li><label>Date of Birth</label>:<input value="${doctor.getPersonInfo().getDateOfBirth() }" name="personInfo.dateOfBirth" type="text" id="datepicker" readonly/></li>
        <li><label>Gender</label>:
               <label>Male</label><form:radiobutton path="personInfo.sex" value="male"/>
                <label>Female</Label><form:radiobutton path="personInfo.sex" value="female"/>
        </li>
        <li><label>Phone Number</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getContacts().get(0).getPhoneNumber() }" path="personInfo.contacts[0].phoneNumber"/></li>
        <li><label>Mobile Number</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getContacts().get(0).getMobileNumber() }" path="personInfo.contacts[0].mobileNumber" type="text" required="true"/></li>
        <li><label>E-mail Address</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getEmail() }" path="personInfo.email" type="text" required="true"/></li>
    </ul>
    </section>

    <section>
    <header><h3>Address</h3></header>
    <ul class="fields">
        <li><label>Address</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(0).getAddress() }" path="personInfo.addresses[0].address"/></li>
        <li><label>City</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(0).getCity() }" path="personInfo.addresses[0].city"/></li>
        <li><label>Province</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(0).getProvince() }" path="personInfo.addresses[0].province"/></li>
        <li><label>Zip Code</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(0).getZipCode() }" path="personInfo.addresses[0].zipCode" /></li>
    </ul>

</section>

<section>
    <header><h3>Account Details</h3></header>
    <ul class="fields">
        <li><label>Username</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getUser().getUsername() }" path="user.username" required="true"/></li>
        <li><label>Password</label>:<form:password value="${ doctor.getUser().getPassword() }" path="user.password" required="true"/></li>
    </ul>
</section>

<section>
    <header>
        <h3>Hospital Details</h3>
    </header>
    <ul class="fields">
        <li><label>Name</label>:<form:input value="${doctor.getPersonInfo().getCompanyName() }" path="personInfo.companyName"/></li>
        <li><label>Employment Status</label>:
             <label>Full-time</label><form:radiobutton path="employmentStatus" value="full-time"/>
             <label>Part-time</Label><form:radiobutton path="employmentStatus" value="part-time"/>
        </li>
        <li><label>Phone Number</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getContacts().get(1).getPhoneNumber()}" path="personInfo.contacts[1].phoneNumber"/></li>
        <li><label>Work Mobile Number</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getContacts().get(1).getPhoneNumber()}" path="personInfo.contacts[1].mobileNumber" /></li>
        <li><label>Address</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(1).getAddress() }" path="personInfo.addresses[1].address" /></li>
        <li><label>City</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(1).getCity() }" path="personInfo.addresses[1].city"/></li>
        <li><label>Province</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(1).getProvince() }" path="personInfo.addresses[1].province" /></li>     
        <li><label>Zip Code</label>:<form:input value="${ doctor.getPersonInfo().getAddresses().get(1).getZipCode() }" path="personInfo.addresses[1].zipCode" />

    </ul>
</section>  


        <section>
            <ul class="btnForm">
                <li><span class="btn"><input type="submit"
                        value="Save" class="btnS"></span></li>
                <li><span class="btn"><input type="button"
                        value="Cancel" class="btnCancel" onClick="viewPotentialsList()"></span></li>
            </ul>
```

**Error**

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [emrMVC] in context with path [/emr] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1] with root cause
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:657)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.updateDoctor(Unknown Source)
    at com.ust.emr.controller.admin.EditDoctorController.updateDoctor(EditDoctorController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you please post your exception here?

Comment: Your post seems to post some form data. As part of request you are receiving @ModelAttribute("doctor") also, does this object have values of the row which you want to update?

Comment: @zeus done posting the exception

Comment: @prabhat i sent the Doctor model itself to the jsp so that it serves as the form. The fields to be edited is up to the user so it's really undetermined which fields are updated.

Comment: Missing id/version for the referenced User and/or PersonInfo objects?

Comment: @jukka but the error appeared after the the update doctor was executed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. A lot of classes or entities are dependent on the doctor, the entity I'm updating. In order for the batch update to execute successfully, I had to place a  on the jsp, fetching all the ids of the dependent classes. Thank you!